# Create an archive inside of an archive in C# with ZipArchive class

Tags: c#, .net, zip, .net-4.5, archive

As the title says, I am trying to create a zip inside of a zip.

I have a zip archive created at a variable called "TargetFilePath"

```
var projectDirectoryPath = currentProjectViewModel.DirectoryPath;
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(projectDirectoryPath, TargetFilePath+@"/Project.zip");
```

The above will not work, I am assuming because the path c:\test.zip\project.zip is not a valid path.

edit for clarity: i literally want to zip up some files and place that zip inside of another archive. It has to be using System.IO.Compression, no 3rd party methods.

From my understanding you have to create a target address for the zip files, and,also from my experience, that target address cannot be an invalid path such as  "c:\test.zip\project.zip"

Comment: a recursive call maybe?

Comment: If `projectDirectoryPath` has a .zip file + whatever other files in it, then it should just work. If you already have a .zip file, and want to add a zip file into that, then [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158346(v=vs.110).aspx) is one way to do it but it looks like a pain to me. I would just work inside out, create the inner zip files first, then zip that up, instead of creating the outter zip and adding the other file into it. See the remarks [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) for other options.

Comment: Alternatively, extract the existing zip file to a directory, copy your other zip into it, then zip that folder up using the same command you have. I say this because that [ZipArchive.CreateEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158346(v=vs.110).aspx) looks unwieldy where you can't just, "add this file to the zip", you have to stream the file into it somehow. If you have the resources then just use some IO and some time to make life easier, IMO.

Comment: This question is unclear. It seems you are trying to use `projectDirectoryPath` as a source for the data to be archived, and it's clear that the syntax you're trying to use cannot possibly work, but where do you actually want this data to go? Do you literally want one .zip archive to contain another? Or do you want a new folder within the existing .zip archive, where individual files from `projectDirectoryPath` can be found as individual archive entries? What is already in the `TargetFilePath` archive? Where did those files come from?

Comment: Please improve the clarity of the question, including providing a good [mcve] that reliably illustrates the relationships of the files and archives to each other and explain what precisely you're having trouble figuring out.

Comment: i edited for clarity

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create your zip file in a temporary file with the contents of your `projectDirectoryPath` and once that is done you add that file to your target zip archive.

So basically something like this:

```
var projectDirectoryPath = currentProjectViewModel.DirectoryPath;
var tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
try
{
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(projectDirectoryPath, tempFile);

    using (var archive = ZipFile.Open(TargetFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(tempFile, "Project.zip", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
    }
}
finally
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(tempFile);
}
```

I suggest you use `CompressionLevel.NoCompression` because the zip archive is already compressed and another layer of compression will add no value to it. Using `ZipArchiveMode.Update` when opening the archive is important so the zip file is actually altered. The other values for this enumerator are used to create a new archive from scratch or to open it as read-only.

In the example I used the [`CreateEntryFromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.createentryfromfile.aspx) function. It is a extension method so make sure you have the namespace in the `using` declarations.

It is possible to implement this in a way so no temporary file is required, but that requires a lot more code, as you have to create the new zip file yourself and write it directly to the stream you get when creating a new entry in the `achive`. But for most cases the example I gave should do the job.

Comment: When i use this method, I get an exception that the temp file already exists

Comment: Fixed that. Now it is using a pretty safe method to just generate a temp file. This may still fail in case the file name is already in use. If you want to ensure that this works, you have to loop until you get a free file name and check if the file is already in use.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HyEdu0Sm this code is still creating the same error. I am able to examine the value of the variables and "fileExists" does return false, so i would assume that this would work

Comment: Erm... would be good if you would use the `tempFile` in the `CreateFromDirectory` directory call.

Comment: LOL. thanks man. I had changed it to debug the first time, and never changed it back. Sorry for wasting your time, and thank you for your help.